# Why does my first snippit work, but my second doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to bing a click event to a new `<div />` in jQuery.  The following snippit works (when I click the div, I see the 'clicked' message)  however, the second doesn't.

Could anyone tell me why?

**Working snippet :**

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $display = $('#display'),
            $drawingArea = $('<div />')
                .attr('id', 'drawing-area')
                .click(function() {
                    alert('clicked');
                });

        $display.wrap($drawingArea);
    })
})();
```

**Not working snippet :**  *(The alert 'ready' is fired, but not the click')*

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $display = $('#display'),
            $drawingArea = $('<div />')
                .attr('id', 'drawing-area');
        $display.wrap($drawingArea);

        $drawingArea.ready(function() {
            alert('ready');
            $drawingArea.click(function() {
                alert('clicked');
            })
        });

    })
})();
```

**Update**

Just tried the following:

```
(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $display = $('#display'),
            $drawingArea = $('<div />')
                .attr('id', 'drawing-area');
        $display.wrap($drawingArea);

        $drawingArea.ready(function() {
            alert('ready');

        });

        $drawingArea.click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
        })
    })
})();
```

The 'ready' alert fired, but no 'clicked' alert.

**HTML**:

```
<section id="main">
    <svg id="display" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    </svg>
</section>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Just noticed that, when I click furiously with the chrome dev tools opened this appeads just before the `</html`>

```
<div id="gdx-bubble-container">
   <div id="gdx-bubble-main" style="left: 0px; top: 1023.4375px;">
      <div id="gdx-bubble-close"></div>
      <div id="gdx-bubble-query-container" class="gdx-display-block">
         <div id="gdx-bubble-query">not</div>
         <div id="gdx-bubble-audio-icon" class="gdx-display-block"></div>
         <div id="gdx-bubble-query-container-end"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="gdx-bubble-meaning">Used with an auxiliary verb or “be” to form the negative</div>
      <div id="gdx-bubble-options-tip" class="gdx-display-block">Tip: Didn't want this definition pop-up? Try setting a trigger key in <a href="chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/options.html" target="_blank">Extension Options</a>.</div>
      <div id="gdx-bubble-attribution" class="gdx-display-none">
         <a target="_blank"></a>
         <div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="gdx-bubble-more" class="gdx-display-block"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/search?q=define+not">More »</a></div>
   </div>
   <div id="gdx-arrow-container">
      <div id="gdx-arrow-main" style="top: 1145.4375px; left: 10px;">
         <div id="gdx-bubble-arrow-inner-down"></div>
         <div id="gdx-bubble-arrow-outer-down"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to take out the $drawingArea.click(function() { from the $drawingArea.ready ?

Comment: what is inside the div? If the div is empty, there is nothing to click on.

Comment: @LiadLivnat That's what the first example does, but it doesn't matter when the question is *why* it doesn't work.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert The `div` has an `svg` inside it, I'll add the HTML to the question.

Comment: This is working fine: $display.parent().click(function(), I'm checking why

Comment: FYI, binding a `ready` listener to `$drawingArea` is superfluous as it's contained by your `$(document).ready` handler which has already executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies within the functionality of [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. **A copy of this structure** will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements.

In other words when you say `$display.wrap($drawingArea);` you're creating a *copy* of `$drawingArea`. When you later add the click event to it, it won't be added to the copy which is actually in the DOM.

The first snippet works because you're adding the click event *before* the `.wrap()` operation, so the click event is copied along with the rest of the element.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out from [**Juhana**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717807/975520) (+1) wrap create a copy of the structure, so your div `$display` will not be wrapped from the object itself.

You can use the parent of the element `$display` to make you selector:

```
'use strict';

(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $display = $('#display'),
            $drawingArea = $('<div />')
                .attr('id', 'drawing-area');
        $display.wrap($drawingArea);

        $display.parent().ready(function() {
            alert('ready');
            $display.parent().click(function() {
                alert('clicked');
            })
        });
    })
})();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5ch9W/1/

Answer (score -2):

You are missing a semicolon here:

```
        drawingArea.click(function() {
            alert('clicked');
        });
       ---^
```

Comment: I didn't know Javascript allowes missing `;` even in strict mode.

Comment: Not the downvoter but this isn't the issue, in some situations semicolons can be omitted - they're automatically inserted when the code is run. This can cause issues so it's not best practice, here's a good article: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/